# TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined. in node js

Tags: node.js

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
>       at /Users/junggri/Desktop/web2-nodejs/syntax/main.js:15:36
>       at FSReqWrap.args [as oncomplete] (fs.js:140:20)

here is my code in node js

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var url = require('url');
var app = http.createServer(function(request,response){
var _url = request.url;
var queryData = url.parse(_url, true).query;
var pathname = url.parse(_url, true).pathname;
if(pathname === '/'){
if(queryData.id === undefined){
fs.readdir('./data', function(error, filelist){
var title = 'Welcome';
var description = 'Hello, Node.js';
var list = '<ul>';
for(var i =0; i<filelist.length; i++){
list = list + `<li><a href="/?id=${filelist[i]}">${filelist[i]}</a></li>`;}
list = list+'</ul>';
var template = `
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>WEB1 - ${title}</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<h1><a href="/">WEB</a></h1>
${list}
<h2>${title}</h2>
<p>${description}</p>
</body>
</html>
`;
response.writeHead(200);
response.end(template);
})
```

Comment: Don't ignore the `error` parameter - always check it first, that's why it's the first parameter

Comment: I think the problem is because of the asynchronous operation. Can you please try it by using fs.readdirSync() method. I hope it will solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be an issue reading the directory. As pointed out in the earlier answer check the error argument you have in your callback. It will give ou the necessary details.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
var filelist = fs.readdirSync('./data/');
```